# What does @parm mean or imply in C++?

Tags: c++

I need to establish an initial understanding of this term before I can understand it in all the general contexts that I've seen. (And I'm fairly certain this is a well-known term.)

What does @parm mean? It's used a lot by basic programmers, (I am definitely new to programming) and it's always within a comment, so to me it doesn't seem to have any functionality but does seem to imply something. I've researched it and can't find anything but instances of the term nested within other questions.

Comment: Looks like some sort of documentation-generator from comments markup to me.

Comment: You aren't the only one wondering https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.c/zWdSpmsyYMk

Answer (score 4):

It's a hint used by doxygen and other code parsers to give information about a specific parameter in a comment; it has no functional impact on the code.

Answer (score 4):

It's part of the doxygen automated code documentation syntax.

It can be used to provide more details about a specific parameter to a function or method.

You can read more on it [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdparam) (Note: '@' and '\' in doxygen with relation to commands are interchangeable).

Comment: That clears up a lot, thanks. However, the information at that link doesn't use '@parm' at all. Instead it uses '@param'. Are they interchangeable?